# Image from clipboard copied to Excel shows up as question mark

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

About 10% of the time, when I paste a screenshot from my clipboard into Excel, it shows up as a question mark.

90% of the time, it works fine.

What's going on?

[image]

Comment: Most likely just not a compatible image. Otherwise something amiss with Excel.

Comment: Do you know the file format about the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/fixing-powerpoint-annoyances/0596100043/ch04.html) refers to Powerpoint and it's probably a bit old, I assume individual Office products have a lot in common when it comes to the same functions. Perhaps it still applies:

> This icon shows up when the Office clipboard hasn’t been activated or has lost its focus to another application. To activate the clipboard and maintain its focus, open PowerPoint before you copy whatever it is you’re copying, and after you’ve copied it, go directly to PowerPoint and paste. Don’t stop anywhere on the way.